# Mysql docker won't grant permissions for user

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm creating Mysql docker container from such dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

MAINTAINER developer

# The official MySQL docker image will run all .sh and .sql scripts found in this directory
# the first time the container is started.
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

init.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS rtb;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS rtb_test;
CREATE USER 'rtb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rtb.* TO 'rtb'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rtb_test.* TO 'rtb'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
# Always use UTC
default-time-zone='+00:00'

# To turn off strict mode (alas, we started out that way, will be work to turn it on)
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max-allowed-packet = 16M

### Per-thread Buffers
sort-buffer-size = 2M
read-buffer-size = 128K
read-rnd-buffer-size = 256K
join-buffer-size = 256K

### Temp Tables
tmp-table-size = 64M
max-heap-table-size = 64M

#### Storage Engines
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb = FORCE
```

The issue here is that Mysql is not granting permissions for rtb_test database when creating the container, but granting permissions for database rtb for rtb user... But syntax is correct, I can run that code manually from inside the container by root user and it grants privileges for user rtb

I have another project with same `init.sql` file (just another databases/usernames) and all working correctly.

Any idea what is wrong here? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this an `_` wildcard thing? Although it looks like it should match anyway with the wildcard, to match on `_` exactly in a db name you need to escape it: `ON \`rtb\_test\`.* TO`. [Grant quoting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-quoting)

Comment: well, I'm not sure about wildcard, but as I mentioned I'm using the same code on another project and in database names there also has `_` and it works there... but anyway I'll try to escape `_`